# Join many to one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

In Codeigniter I am tryign to join two tables with a one-to-many relation. I want to get one result from my table `housetype` and all of its values/members from other table `housetype_member`:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join('housetype_member', 'housetype_member.housetype_id = housetype.PkId', 'left');
$result = $this->db->get_where('housetype', array('PkId' => $id));

return $result->result();
```

So far I get such result:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[28]
      public 'PkID' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'Name' => string 'Classic' (length=7)
      public 'image' => string '1449063250.jpg' (length=14)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[30]
      public 'PkID' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'Name' => string 'Classic' (length=7)
      public 'image' => string '1449063288.gif' (length=14)
```

First two object values (PkID, Name) are from the first table and the last one (image) is from the second left table. Everything is good but I get an array with two elements, when I only need one `housetype` object.

Is there a way to write above code so that my returned object would look like this:

```
object(stdClass)[28]
  public 'PkID' => string '4' (length=1)
  public 'Name' => string 'Classic' (length=7)
  public 'image' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '1449063250.jpg' (length=14)
      1 => string '1449063288.gif' (length=14)
```

I need one result from the first table and to it I want to join all of its members from the second table.

Can it be done with Codeigniters active record, can it be done at all?

Answer (score 0):

Add `group_by()` clause to your query.

```
$this->db->group_by('housetype.PkId');
```

Comment: all this does is that it groups my results into one object and I loose all images except one which is the last one. I need array of all images